# Looking for CMS Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

This is my current insert image function, i'm using TinyMCE [image: Screenshot]
instead of manually putting the images on the uploads folder then manually inserting the directory when inserting image to the website, is there a something i can use? something like on Wordpress, where i can just browse or drag the image to upload, then when inserting i have a gallery of all uploaded images then just click to use.

Answer (score 0):

Something like : http://www.dropzonejs.com/

> DropzoneJS is an open source library that provides drag’n’drop file uploads with image previews.

This provides the client side interface to drag/drop an image. Your code has to send it to the server with an ajax request that can be saved to either the database or to a folder. For each image, you'll have a unique pointer identifying the image that can be used to manipulate it.

Alternately, if you don't want to manage the backend (uploading/hosting images), you can use an API e.g. [imgur](https://api.imgur.com/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is that only for upload? how about if i'm going to use the image? do i have to type the image location manually or does it have a gallery?

Comment: @Hansmagz Please see updated answer